# The method addLayer(U) is not applicable for the arguments (Minecraft)

Tags: eclipse, arguments, minecraft

I have an error in eclipse saying that the method addLayer is not applicable for the arguments (argument)
Thanks in advance! ^^

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method addLayer(U) in the type RendererLivingEntity is not applicable for the arguments (LayerCape)   RenderPlayer.java   /Client/src/net/minecraft/client/renderer/entity    line 40 Java Problem
The method addLayer(U) in the type RendererLivingEntity is not applicable for the arguments (LayerEnderDragonEyes)    RenderDragon.java   /Client/src/net/minecraft/client/renderer/entity    line 30 Java Problem
The method addLayer(U) in the type RendererLivingEntity is not applicable for the arguments (LayerEndermanEyes) RenderEnderman.java /Client/src/net/minecraft/client/renderer/entity    line 24 Java Problem
The method addLayer(U) in the type RendererLivingEntity is not applicable for the arguments (LayerSheepWool)   RenderSheep.java    /Client/src/net/minecraft/client/renderer/entity    line 15 Java Problem
The method addLayer(U) in the type RendererLivingEntity is not applicable for the arguments (LayerWolfCollar)   RenderWolf.java /Client/src/net/minecraft/client/renderer/entity    line 19 Java Problem
The method addLayer(U) in the type RendererLivingEntity is not applicable for the arguments (LayerSpiderEyes)    RenderSpider.java   /Client/src/net/minecraft/client/renderer/entity    line 15 Java Problem

Answer (score 0):

The arguments are not of the right type so you probably have to change some of the classes. But what are you doing so this error occurs? If you are new to developing and trying to create a own client please watch a tutorial and learn minecraft developing that way, it will help you more and you will leran faster.